# Any way to make "Validate Project Settings" warning go away in Xcode 4.3/4.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

Has anyone been able to make the **Validate Project Settings** / **Update to recommended settings** warning go away in Xcode since 4.3?

[image: Xcode project warning]

It wants to make some changes that I don't want to accept. I've tried both "Don't Perform Changes" and unchecking the changes I don't want and then "Perform Changes" but the warning refuses to go away. In the past one or the other of those has always made it go away. Xcode has already up'd the project format verison in the project file to the 4.3 value, i.e.,

```
LastUpgradeCheck = 0430
```

but it still seems to continue to check.

`rdar://11008193` (closed as a duplicate of 10944711)

Comment: Why not just accept then? usually it just takes a snapshot of your project, then updates the .xcodeproj file to the newest recommended format.

Comment: Because they are settings that are not right for my project. And the `LastUpgradeCheck` has already been bumped.

Comment: More specifically, which settings aren't right?

Comment: In my experience, it suggests to change each scheme's debugger from GDB to LLDB. (I'd love to, but LLDB isn't significantly more reliable than GDB, yet.)

Comment: Right. My biggest issues are debugger and compiler (clang still has problems with C++).

Comment: I'm building Second Life viewer on Mac and have this problem. The code doesn't compile with Clang. There are about 50 different build schemes in this and there is no way I'm going one-by-one as Cliff suggests below. It would take hours. The only thing that has done it for me is to agree to the changes then restore to the snapshot it takes before agreeing. Then it built without the warning.

Comment: I'd like to turn the warning off because I'm using a read-only project from github (a secondary project in my workspace) and don't want to have the project show up as dirty with a change I can't commit.

Answer (score 3):

Try editing the Schemes for your project. Product > Edit Scheme. Go into each scheme associated with the project and explicitly set the values you want. This fixed it for me.

Comment: What value would you set if you didn't want it to recommend the GDB->LLDB switch?

Comment: GDB in the Debug scheme for Debugger

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I have GDB set for Debugger in the Debug scheme. Nonetheless, Xcode warns me to "Validate Project Settings" and "Update to recommended settings".

Answer (score 0):

Set `LastUpgradeCheck` to 9999 in `project.pbxproj`.

Set `LastUpgradeVersion` to 9999 in your `.xcschemes` if you use them.

This answer is from Jeff Johnson's excellent blog: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/validate-project-settings-never.html